# Is "more-point function" correct? (mathematics)

Tags: mathematics

How do I describe in English (i.e. without mathematical symbols) the following mathematical object,  if I want to stress comparison with the two-point function?

> The *n*-point Green's function for *n*>2.

Background: For each natural number *n*>2 or *n*=2, there is an *n*-point Green's function.

Options:

> 1. higher-point function (wrong)
> 2. more-point function (more than 2, but still not clear)
> 3. many-point function (many sounds much more than, say, 3)
> 4. higher-order-[point]-function
> 5. higher-rank-[point]-function

Which is the right terminology?

Comment: can you say `higher-order` instead?

Comment: @costrom doesn't it sound like *derivative*? I also thought of *rank*, but I have no idea. To me it should sound like *[higher-number-of]-points Green's function*.

Comment: You might consider ***multi-point***, since the *multi-* prefix wouldn't normally be used for just *two* points.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh, that's the word it seems to work : )

Comment: A brief time spent in the google reveals that *multi-point* is indeed the term of art for Green's function.

Comment: @deadrat Could you make an answer out of your comment? YOu know, tie off some old frayed ends?